# PHP Instalar Composer con Putty

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda para instalar Composer desde cPanel con Putty

Me muestra este error, estoy siguiente este video:
https://youtu.be/DsgWKuGk3yM?t=1m56s

El error que me muestra es:
[image: Al enviar el comando PHP INSTALLER --CHECK]

Answer (score 1):

Te está diciendo que hay algo mal configurado en la extensión sushosin de PHP.

Te indica que añadas al final del php.ini que utilizas `/opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini` la siguiente línea:

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```